# Foursquare API - Cannot query using Category ID and same results keep coming back

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a Foursquare API to find all the Bus Stops via category ID (52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b4f) within a set radius from a set location in New York. I am using the following code:

```
    CLIENT_ID = '123'
    CLIENT_SECRET = '456'
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude
    intent = "checkin"
    VERSION = '20180604'
    radius = 5000
    LIMIT = 10
    category = "52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b4f"
```

and these variables are passed to the URL as follows:

```
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={}, 
    {}&intent{}&v={}&radius={}&limit={}&category{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, 
    latitude, longitude, intent, VERSION, radius, LIMIT, category)
```

which gives

**https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search&client_id=123&client_secret=456&ll=40.7149555,-74.0153365&intentcheckin&v=20180604&radius=5000&limit=10&category52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b4f**

However, this query returns locations which are not Bus Stops - but the category IDs that are being returned are also not to be found on the Foursquare Dev website, as follows:

[image]

In addition, whenever I change the ID to test the code, it brings back the same info. I cant get it to change. Something isnt updating somewhere and I keep restarting my notebook with no effect.

1. Do we know why my code isn't bringing back bus stop location?
2. Does it matter the order that I send in the URL? e.g. could I define intent after LL or Category after client ID?
3. Why am I getting the same return each time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a workaround to search under a query using the text from the category ID instead. Not perfect, but gets me to where I need to be.